# Why am I getting NullPointerException when I'm not dereferencing anything that's pointing to Null?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
int playerNum,cardNum;
Cards card=null; 
        
for(playerNum=0;playerNum<=NUMPLAYERS-1;playerNum++)
{ 
    //some code...
            
    for(cardNum=1;cardNum<=5;cardNum++)
    {
     card=( deckOfCards.deal() ); 
     players[playerNum].setHand_1by1(card);//I get NullPointerException for using the method here
                
     //some code...
                    
    }
}
```

---

```
class Hand
 {
     private Cards[] hand=new Cards[5];
     private int counter;
     
     //no constructor, just a setter.
     public void setHand_1by1(Cards card)
     {
         if(counter>=hand.length)
         {
             System.out.printf("Hand is full");
         }
         else
         {
             hand[counter]=card;
             counter++;
         }
        
     }
//some code...
}
```

I understand that you get a `NullPointerException` when you try to dereference something that's pointing to nothing(ie `null`).

1)But `card` of `Cards` type is pointing to something due to the method `deckOfCards.deal()` so that's not the problem, must be something in the method.

2)In the `setHand_1by1()`, `hand[counter]` is of Cards type.  All I did was make it point to valid memory containing data of `Cards` type in the `else` block.

Why am I then getting a `NullPointerException` error?

Edit:
Just showing how I created my `players`:

```
Hand[] players=new Hand[NUMPLAYERS];
```

Comment: How about `players[...]`?

Comment: You access `players`. And either that array or one of the elements accessed by `players[playerNum]` is null. But you're not showing how you populate that array, so there's no telling.

Comment: `players` is of `Hand` type. I'm populating it using the `setHand_1by1` method and get the error on the first try

Comment: No, in `setHand_1by1` you're populating each `Hand`'s array of `Card`s, but not the `player` array outside that contains all `Hand`s. Show *that* code.

Comment: You only create the `players` array, but you never put any `Hand` object in it. So all the elements are still `null`

Comment: I assume `players[playerNum]` is `null`. Do you create the Hand objects anywhere?

Comment: @QBrute @Johannes, you are absolutely right, players[playerNum] points to `null`. The concept of array of objects is tripping me. Could someone convert that into an answer? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `Hand` object reference in `players[playernum]` to be able to call a `Hand` method on it.

The `players` array that you created(of type `Hand`), is really just an array that can hold `Hand`(or its subclass') object references. Initially, the references are all `null`, and you are required to populate them yourself.

About your array of objects comments, note that there isn't ever an array of objects, only an array of object references. The references point to places where the object actually resides(usually the heap).